# UML modeling tool for Linux

Tags: linux, uml

I am starting a new project using Eclipse under Linux and I am looking for a UML 2.x **modeling tool** not just a diagramming tool.

- Do anyone has experience with UML plugin for Eclipse? Does it support all UML diagrams?
- Do you recommend another modeling tool?
- If you have been in a similar situation, what did you end up doing anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used both [BOUML](http://bouml.free.fr/) and [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). As i don't use Eclipse,  they are both external tools, though.
I've preferred BOUML, because it's lighter than ArgoUML, and it is more powerful when it comes to reverse engineering. I've used it for automatically generate class diagrams, for building them from scratch, and to design sequence diagrams too. unfortunately, even if it's quite powerful, it is in Qt3 (so the UI is not really beautiful on my KDE4), and the developer has decided to stop development...

Comment: ArgoUML does not support UML 2.0 which is disadvantage.

Comment: There's also StarUML: http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

Comment: I stopped using at BOUML after its developer added a nag screen.

Comment: These all suck.

Answer (score 6):

I like [Violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php), it works as a standalone application, as well as a plugin for Eclipse.

I also like [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia), but Violet looks a lot better.

Comment: Violet does not support component or deployment diagrams but it's UI is very nice indeed. Thank you very much.

Comment: @M.Sameer it hasn't received any updates in quite some time, I think that's why. and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

[Astah](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/product/astah-uml.html) is written in Java and works well on Linux.

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) is a Windows program, but it comes with [instructions](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/faq/enterprise-architect-WINE.html) how to run it in Wine, and this actually works. (Testet on Kubuntu 10.10)

Comment: I have tried it myself and it works well but the fonts does not look fine.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what these resources do and why do you recommend these as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my answer to [Best free UML authoring tool](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/best-free-uml-authoring-tool/57598#57598). It refers Dia, StarUML and argoUML, Visual Paradigm, POPP/POI (Plain Old PowerPoint/Impress), gliffy.com, yEd, Red Koda. Most of them work under Linux.

If they don't, you can make them work under Wine (e.g. Visual Paradigm).

Comment: I have looked at this question but some of them are just diagramming tools and I wanted to know more about Eclipse plugin. Actually you are right about wine. I was thinking if I did not get good recommendations, I will use EA under wine. It's working fine although not looking very good.

Comment: Visual Paradigm for UML works well in Linux, without Wine.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) in Eclipse 4.2.

- It can be used as integrated tool in eclipse or it can be downloaded from their website and used as a standalone tool.
- It supports UML 2
- It supports almost all UML diagrams.
- It can be used with other eclipse modeling tools to generate and reverse engineer code (Java code in my case).

Answer (score -1):

Dia Diagram Editor is the one I use. You can find it [here](http://live.gnome.org/Dia). Its pretty simple to use and light weight. Easily installs as well.

Comment: Dia is a diagramming tool not a modeling tool. It's like Visio for windows.

Comment: @M.Sameer it also does UML, see [here](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Screenshots)

Comment: @Mahmoud Yes it supports UML but as a diagramming tool not a modeling tool.

Comment: @M.Sameer : why use a UML modeling tool? What are the benfits? How does it work?

Comment: @Imran In modeling tool all design elements are maintained in a model regardless of they appear in a diagram or not. For example, When you are drawing sequence diagram, it makes you select the method to call from the list of methods available in the object. It knows them from the class hierarchy in the model regardless if they are shown in a class diagram or not. Enterprise Architect is a great modeling tool example. I prefer modeling tools because they help keep the design consistent and makes you more productive.

Comment: @M.Sameer - thanx for the info, seems extremely interesting

Comment: @Imran you are most welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

I use EclipseUML Omondo with Eclipse 3.6 Helios and Linux. 
It Works really well but the tool is very expensive !!

Answer (score -1):

I vote for [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/)

Unlike Umbrello, doesn't keep crashing (on Linux/gnome)

Unlike Dia it draws itself so I'm not wasting my time trying to keep objects attached to each other.

It's free.

It's self-documenting so I was able to start using it immediately.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Poseidon for UML](http://www.gentleware.com/) some years ago, it runs well under Linux. It's a tool with a lot of features, a nice user interface and it can integrate to Eclipse for it's professional version. Despite of it's community version, it's not free at all.